# checking if graph is bipartite along with adding every new edge

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Given multiple inputs of the edges in a graph such as(first line being number of connections):

```
4
1 2
2 3
5 6
1 5
```

I have to check that after each input whether the graph remains bipartite or not, we will just break if graph is non-bipartite.
I think this is some graph coloring problem but I am unable to implement it, please help me by providing some algorithm to do so.

Comment: Graph coloring is right. Try to find a two-coloring, which is very straigtforward (there's only one choice for each but the first node). If such coloring exists, it is bipartite.

Comment: can u please elaborate, i haven't done any graph coloring problem , i just came to know about it when i started finding answer for this question.

Comment: Do you have any time constrains?

Comment: @DavidWinder actually its a subpart of this https://www.codechef.com/JULY18A/problems/GEARS question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph is bipartite iff you can find a two-coloring of the graph. This is quite easy to implement, as there is no backtracking involved; for each succesive node, there is just one color available, and if that color is not possible, because one of the neighbors already has that color, than the graph is not bipartite.

You can, e.g. implement this as a depth first search, keeping track of two sets for nodes with color A and color B, respectively. Each time you expand new nodes, you switch the color, and if that node should be colored A, but is already in the B set, the graph is not bipartite.

Your case seems to be a bit different, though, checking whether the graph is bipartite after adding each individual edge. You could still run DFS on the entire graph in each iteration, but this might be too slow.

Instead, keep track of two sets for nodes with color A and color B for each (still) disconnected subgraph. So when you add an edge `(x, y)`:

- check the subgraphs `x` and `y` belong to (using some sort of map/dictionary)
- if neither belongs to a subgraph, start a new subgraph
- if one belongs to a subgraph, but the other is not yet in a graph, give the other node the opposite color of the already contained node
- if both belong to different subgraphs, merge the subgraphs into one (merging the color sets); this might require flipping the colors of one of the graphs so that `x` and `y` do not end up with the same color; make sure to update the map so that all those nodes point to the merged graph
- if both belong to the same subgraph, they have to be in different color sets, otherwise the graph is not bipartite

In your case, the subgraphs map might look like this after each edge:

```
1 2 -> {1: ({1}, {2}), 2: (see 1)}
2 3 -> {1: ({1, 3}, {2}), 2: (see 1), 3: (see 1)}
5 6 -> {1: ({1, 3}, {2}), 2: (see 1), 3: (see 1), 5: ({5}, {6}), 6: (see 5)}
1 5 -> {1: ({1, 3, 6}, {2, 5}), 2: (see 1), 3: (see 1), 5: (see 1), 6: (see 1)}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...this is helpful